# Controlled execution of a user script in .net framework

Tags: c#, scripting, user-defined-functions, execution

What my users want is to write and add "*stored procedures*" (not SQL) to our system. These procedures contain user logic in *user defined functions*, works on memory objects, use *advanced data structures* like lists, structures, dictionaries. The scripts create in-memory XML files.

The scripts *are not reviewed* by other users – **the execution subsystem must guarantee that the script cannot do any harm against the server**. It is unacceptable that the script access external resources (file system, sql database, etc.), but should use the application public API - best way is using custom object instances methods. So the scripts should communicate the environment during the execution but only through a controlled manner. Cannot eat all the memory, cannot run forever.

The scripts may write output messages which should be captured and displayed. Would be a fortune if there is a way to debug the script execution somehow.

I am newbie in this problem space. The script language is not specified, can be python, powershell, C# script, anything. I found the CSharpScript (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) during the research phase, but I am unsure if this will the best to choose. Does anybofy know a better place to start? How should we solve this problem – as we don’t want to write a script language, define a parser and execute the script on our own. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This may be better suited to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Liam it is not about SQL scripts, the "stored procedures" is a similar example. The script should work memory objects, and not allowed to access any external resources, including sql servers and file systems. This is the problem - how to I enable the scripting support without allowing using some namespaces and objects.

Comment: @IainMNorman thanks, you are right - now I know. :(

Comment: Could you surface your scriptable methods with a secure web API? Then your script writing users could access those API endpoints with JavaScript in node. They could pull objects, process them, and post back changes. Javascript doesn't care about types, all your outputs will be json, so no need for namespaces and objects to be understood by the node script.

That could just be a web dev's answer though :)

Comment: @IainMNorman Ooo it is not Web API, in "API" I mean a set of functions which can be access and use from the scripts. The script can access external resources (files, db entities) only through these functions (authorization), so cannot use System.IO objects and methods, cannot start external programs (like notepad.exe, and so), cannot access web url-s, and so.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer every problem looks like a nail :)

Comment: So what your saying is, you want to create Visual Studio? Look, this question is far too vague, broad and generally ill defined. I'm not sure what your expecting from anyone here?! Your asking how can you process undefined scripts that do undefined things in an undefined language?! What answer are you hoping to get?

Comment: I am searching for a solution to use (for example) C# lang as a base language to allow users write scripts, which I can compile and execute, but restrict this script to access external resources. It is a general problem I think, and I don't want to reinventing the wheel. I don't know if  a user script is execution, how to control or verify the script that it won't do any restricted operation.

Comment: For example you want to include local logic into the flow of data between to points, and allow users to write scripts which examine the data flow and drop exceptions when some bad data is detected. How to add support for that scripts, without allowing the script to access other resources than the data itself (not sending this sensitive data to outside of the company for example).

Answer (score 0):

As it happened, the roslyn (microsoft code analysis) is good feature to compile and build an assembly, then combining with other external DLLs is easy. Using reflection the scripts can be started, so the execution can be initiated.

But controlling the execution time, limiting the resources usage (memory, cpu, ...), limiting the access of external resources (disk,network, db, ...) is not an easy task.